# How do I automatically login to another database from a current website in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

In cakephp I login in to the mysql database no problem. I have an issue where once I login I need to access another database(button click) on the same server on another cakephp website. I dont want the user to login again on the other website.  I cant find information on solving this problem . How do I automatically login to another  cakephp website? 
To be clearer about what I want is that I want the user to login and then click a button and use another cakephp website with a different database without having to login. Setdatasource seems to be staying in the same cakephp website and switching databases

The following code works fine (on my pc) but I I need to automatically login to the website without having to login again

```
echo $this->Html->link( 'link!', 'http://127.0.0.1/maths/numeracyStudents/dashboardst'); 

public $mathdb = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'maths',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);

//called this function from the controller and nothing happens?
public function changedb() {

    $this->NumeracyStudents->setDataSource('mathdb');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your application's app.php,you would create another database configuration like the default one and label it. Then, you will use that config to create a connection.

EDIT: I am assuming you are using CakePHP 2.X

database.php

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {
   public $default = array(
    'datasource'  => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent'  => false,
    'host'        => 'localhost',
    'login'       => 'cakephpuser',
    'password'    => 'c4k3roxx!',
    'database'    => 'my_cakephp_project',
    'prefix'      => ''
    );

   public $otherDb = array(
      'datasource'  => 'Database/Mysql',
      'persistent'  => false,
      'host'        => 'localhost',
      'login'       => 'cakephpuser',
      'password'    => 'c4k3roxx!',
      'database'    => 'my_cakephp_project2',
      'prefix'      => ''**strong text**
   );
}
```

ArticlesController:

```
//inside a function(action) you would call this to set to the other datasource
$this->Articles->setDataSource('otherDb');
```

Comment: i dont get this because the database.php is different to what your saying. there is no newQuery

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have asked what version of cake at you using?

Comment: I am using cakephp 2.x , I  dont get how do I automatically log on to another database  after already logging on?

Comment: I edited my post as I tried the solution offered and it didnt work

Comment: I can be sent to the correct website but to automatically login I dont know how?

 echo $this->Html->link( 'link!', 'http://127.0.0.1/maths/numeracyStudents/dashboardst');

Comment: Are you trying to log them into another application of yours? Or are you trying to use the data from another database?